# Nested references to member functions by member functions of other classes

Tags: c++, class, static, void-pointers, pointer-to-member

I am trying to build a generic stochastic differential equation solver coded by a class `de_solver` which takes some set of differential equations given by a `model` class. This model is fed to the solver through a class `sde` which works interface between model and solver, recasting equations of the original model in two subsets of deterministic + stochastic equations.

There are several problems with my code at the moment which I believe have to deal with inheritance and type conversion. In particular I cannot manage to pass the member functions where model equations are specified to the integrator. First say I have a `model` class of this type:

```
class model{
    ...
    public:
        size_t N_eq;
        model(...); // Assign N_eq and parameters and other stuff
        ...
        int equations_det(double t, const double y_[], double dy_[]); // Define deterministic RHS of equations
        static int equations_gsl_wrapper(double t, const double y_[], double dy_[],void *params); // A wrapper that make equations_det suitable for a GSL solver
        void equations_stoch(double t,double dt,const double y_[], double dy_[],); // The stochastic RHS of the model equations
        static void ode_s_wrapper(double t,const double y_[], double dy_[], void *params); // A wrapper to pass equations_det to the stochastic integrator (in the class `de_solver`).
        int simulate(t,tfin,tstep); // The actual simulator which will invoke the 'de_solver'
};
```

The `static` specification follows from the need to use GSL integrators for the deterministic part of the model, as pointed out [in this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47050842/c-class-member-function-to-gsl-ode-solver/47051126#47051126).

Then, the interfacing class `sde` is such that:

```
class sde{
    ...
    public:
        size_t N_eq;
        sde(size_t N_,
            int (*dtr)(double, const double*, double*, void*),
            void (*stc)(double, double, const double*, double*, void*));
        int (*deterministic)(double t, const double* y_[], double* dy_[], void * params);
        void (*stochastic)(double t,const double y_[], double dy_[], void *params);
        //Then again, akin to the model class, use some `wrappers`
        static int deterministic_wrapper(double t, const double y_[], double dy_[], void * params);
    static void stochastic_wrapper(double t, const double y_[], double *dy_, void *params);
};
```

The idea is to have inside the `sde` class, member functions that are inherited from the whatever model is given. As for the two 'wrappers,' I will clarify on the reason why I am introducing them shortly.

Finally the `de_solver` class is such that:

```
class de_solver{
    sde *sys;
    public:
        de_solver(sde *system); // Will initialize solver with the system put in the `sde` form
        ...
        void integrate(void *params, double *ts, double **sol);
};
```

`model` is declared/defined in separate files (`model.H` and `model.CPP`) with respect to `sde` and `de_solver` (`solvers.h` and `solvers.cpp`).

The idea is to have a `simulate` member function in the `model` class such that

```
int model::simulate(double t, double tfin, double dt){
    // Prepare solver
    // 1. Create the `sde` object from model `sys`
    sde recast_sys(NEQ, model::deterministic_wrapper, model::stochastic_wrapper);
    // 2. Instantiate solver with recast system
    de_solver integrator(&recast_sys);

    // Run simulation
    double *ts = ...   // Output time instants
    double **sol = ... // Output solution
    void *params_base = static_cast<void*>(std::addressof(this)); 
    integrator.integrate(params_base);

    return 1;  // In practice there is some error check on this return condition (omitted here for brevity)
}
```

In summary `sys` invokes the `integrator` which works on deterministic and stochastic parts of the model equation as provided through `recast_sys`. Because the deterministic part of the integrator relies on GSL solvers, I am using the additional parameter argument to pass the pointer to the solver to the actually class member function. In this fashion, inside the `integrator.integrate` member function I have (see [above mentioned post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47050842/c-class-member-function-to-gsl-ode-solver/47051126#47051126))

```
de_solver::integrate(void *params_base, ...){
    ...
    // I allocate an array of two void pointers: the first to the `model` class (assumed to be passed by `params_base`), and the second to the `sde` class
    void **params = (void**)calloc(2,sizeof(void*));
    params[0] = params_base;
    params[1] = reinterpret_cast<void *>(std::addressof(sys)); // the recast system as private member of the sde class

    gsl_odeiv2_driver * d;
    gsl_odeiv2_system system = {sys->deterministic_wrapper, nullptr, sys->NEQ, params};
    d = gsl_odeiv2_driver_alloc_y_new (&system, gsl_odeiv2_step_bsimp, opts.dt, opts.atol, opts.rtol);

...
}

int sde::deterministic_wrapper(double t, const double y_[], double dy_[], void * params){
  assert(params);
  return(static_cast<sde*>(params[1])->deterministic(t,y_,dy_,params)); // This will issue an error: ‘void*’ is not a pointer-to-object type
}

int model::equations_gsl_wrapper(double t, const double y_[], double dy_[], void * params){
  assert(params);
  return(static_cast<model*>(params[0])->ode_gsl(t,y_,dy_)); // This will issue an error: ‘void*’ is not a pointer-to-object type
}
```

Allocating an array of two pointers to voids was taken from [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/206257/freeing-memory-allocated-to-an-array-of-void-pointers). However, it seems that the once used in the wrapper, it produces an error maybe because arithmetic on void arrays is not clear (as pointed out [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3523145/pointer-arithmetic-for-void-pointer-in-c))?

At the moment I cannot compile my code for the errors reported above. Also for some reason, the compiler tells me that the `this` pointer in the `model.simulate` member function generates

```
error: use of deleted function ‘const _Tp* std::addressof(const _Tp&&) [with _Tp = model*]’
```

I suspect that I am messing around with static and non-static member functions and I am not passing them correctly. Any input would be appreciated.

Comment: That's too much detail. Please create a [mcve] and post it.

Comment: Yes indeed, I will do so. Sorry about it. I was trying to keep it as simple as possible. But the overall code is somehow not trivial.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have not fully grasped your entire problem, but the answers seem straightforward enough:

> error: use of deleted function ‘const _Tp* std::addressof(const _Tp&&) [with _Tp = model*]’

The compiler tells you that you are attempting to take the address of the *pointer* to your instance, because you did `std::addressof(this)`. `this` already *is* the pointer you are looking for (a `model*`), cast it to `void*` directly.

> `return(static_cast<model*>(params[0])->ode_gsl(t,y_,dy_)); // This will issue an error: ‘void*’ is not a pointer-to-object type`

When you do `params[0]` you already dereferenced the pointer once (the inbuilt `x[y]` is exactly equivalent to `*(x + y)`) and would end up with a plain `void`, which the compiler does not like. Your *array* of void pointers has another level of indirection:

```
int deterministic_wrapper(double t, /* ... */ void * params) {
  void** voidPtrs = static_cast<void**>(params);
  return static_cast<sde*>(voidPtrs[1])->deterministic(t, /* ... */ params);
}
```

See [here](https://godbolt.org/g/1yJWTb).

The better solution would be to just create a `struct` that holds pointers to your classes (your array of void pointers is basically that, just close enough to [three star programming](http://wiki.c2.com/?ThreeStarProgrammer) that it had you make the above mistake):

```
struct myParams
{
  model* _model;
  sde* _sde;
};

// ...

int deterministic_wrapper(double t, /* ... */ void * params) {
  return static_cast<myParams*>(params)->_sde->deterministic(t, /* ... */ params);
}
```

Note that no matter what, you will have to clean up that memory. If you allocated that array you need to free it, if you `new`'d the struct you need to `delete` it, and if you create it on the stack you need to ensure it lives long enough for all these functions to finish.

Comment: Thanks. Excellent look. Right now it compiles indeed but unfortunately there is still no visibility. So I need to narrow down the problem to a simpler example. Let me work on it and repost accordingly on this.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to [Max Langhof](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9528746/max-langhof) for the suggestion the code now runs fine. The issue with visibility that I mentioned was related to a wrong passing of addresses of class methods.

In the above code example, in `model::simulate` method I was initializing the `sde recast_sys` by

```
// Prepare solver
// 1. Create the `sde` object from model `sys`
sde recast_sys(NEQ, model::deterministic_wrapper, model::stochastic_wrapper);
```

instead the correct way to pass the address of my `::*_wrapper` functions, is by `this` pointer, i.e.

```
sde recast_sys(NEQ, this->deterministic_wrapper, this->stochastic_wrapper);
```